# Clarification on preload img script

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'd like to try this preload img script found on a previous stackoverflow question- [Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

for clarification's sake, my image path is img/bg/image1.jpg will I need to change anything in this script for it to work? Also, do I need any other files like a specific jquery version? How can I test that it is working?

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}   
preload([
    'img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/anotherOne.jpg',
    'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]);
```

Comment: open developer tools and look at network traffic and look when and how many times it sends request for image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to load [jQuery](http://jquery.com/download/) and of course put the correct image path in the array

```
preload([
    'img/bg/image1.jpg'
]);
```

What the script does is create an `<img>` tag in memory and loads the image with the given source. That's it. It won't appear on screen unless you add the `<img>` to the DOM.

If you have a debug tool like Firebug, you can look at the "NET" tab and verify that the image is being loaded in memory.

Comment: thanks- and if my path was images/bg/image1.png would that work as well? Would I need to change this line:  $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
 for any reason? i downloaded jquery-1.9.1

Comment: nevermind- I changed to $('<images/>')[0].src = this; which is the same path that I now have and the page is now loading much faster. Thanks for your help